# Bash script variable syntax: with some commands it works, with others it does not

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, tilde

I do not understand the behaviour of this variable:

```
SSH_CONFIG_FILE="~/.ssh/config"
echo $SSH_CONFIG_FILE
ls -l $SSH_CONFIG_FILE
ls -l ~/.ssh/config
```

This is the output:

```
~/.ssh/config
ls: cannot access '~/.ssh/config': No such file or directory
-rw------- 1 pm domain^users 1229 Sep 19 10:52 /home/pm/.ssh/config
```

Why does `echo` work with the $ notation, and `ls` does not?

I tried surrounding the variable with "", '', ``, {}, [] with no improvement.

Comment: Note that `echo` outputs a tilde, not the user's home directory path (as `echo ~/.ssh/config` would do).  If that is what you mean by "works", then you should not be surprised that `ls` cannot list the file in a sub-directory of a directory called (literally) `~`.

Comment: This question is closed with the wrong duplicate. This is not about quotes. The question contains an example without quotes that behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: @Kaz which example? The echo, first ls and second ls all behave exactly as expected - the tilde from the result of a variable expansion isn't expanded, a plain tilde is. And the tilde from the result of the variable expansion is there because it wasn't expanded inside quotes when assigning to the variable.

Comment: @muru Question says, "why does `echo` work with the `$` notation and `ls` does not?" I.e. why can we `echo $SSH_CONFIG_FILE` and see `~/.ssh/config` as expected but `ls $SSH_CONFIG_FILE` reports an error? OP expects the unquoted `$SSH_CONFIG_FILE` in the `ls` command to be resolved with the tilde.

Comment: @Kaz and that expectation isn't valid - it arises from a misunderstanding which is addressed in the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put quotes around tilde `~` if you expect the shell to expand it to your home, so:

```
SSH_CONFIG_FILE=~/.ssh/config
```

if you have space(s); do

```
var=~/'foo bar/file'
```

With the quotes on tilde, you prevent the shell to expand it to treat *literally*.

Comment: While this is true (if you want the tilde to be expanded to `$HOME` - _never_ is such a strong word ;) ), it might be worthwile clearing the confusion by explaining why it didn't work in the invocation `ls -l $SSH_CONFIG_FILE` where the variable was not surrounded by quotes.